# Standard errors for estimates of smoothing parameters

Tags: time-series, forecasting

My question is based on the "*forecast*"  package for R used in [Forecasting with Exponential Smoothing. The State Space Approach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540719164) - Hyndman et al. 2008. I am using the `ets` function to estimate the parameters of a model.

Is there a way to obtain standard errors for the estimates of the smoothing parameters?

Answer (score 4):

Not all methods lead to analytic expressions (preferably based on proper asymptotic results) that provides this.

But the bootstrap allows you to approximate this via simulation. In essence, you generate (lots of) surrogate 'fake' data sets, employ your estimator on each of these and then use the population of your estimates to make inferences.  However, doing bootstrapping in a time series context has its own challenges...

Comment: +1 it is always nice to bootstrap something. On the other hand every challenge is easy with R: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/boot/html/tsboot.html

Comment: Thanks Dirk and mbq. I have one time series I collected. I am not using a data generating process to produce different series. So in this case I understand that I cannot get std deviations? Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: You could try 'chunked' resampling. Google for block bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

The ets() function uses maximum likelihood estimation. So it would be possible to obtain standard errors based on the Hessian matrix in the usual way. However, in forecasting, the value of the model parameters is usually of very limited interest -- what we care about are the forecasts and their variances.

I can't think of a situation where you might want a confidence interval for a smoothing parameter, for example. What could you do with the information that the "true" value of alpha (whatever that means) lies between 0.2 and 0.4?

Consequently, I have not included the calculation of the standard errors of parameters in the package.

Comment: Point taken.

The problem appeared because the estimates of the smoothing parameters of the best fitting model (an ETS(M,A,N) ) are 0.0001 and 0.9999 which I think are the set limits for the possible values the estimates can take. So I was trying to find out what was going on. 

I was looking for standard errors because I'm used to finding out about a model's parameters' distributions whenever I have to estimate one..:) thinking that if they vary too much they are not too reliable.

Comment: I did bootstrap as advised earlier. I found that the standard deviation was not that useful because the distribution was very skewed.

Comment: @noworries. Yes, they are the boundaries of the parameter region. A value close to zero is not a problem -- it indicates the associated state variable is extremely stable and essentially does not change over time. A value close to one usually indicates the model is trying to adapt quickly to each new observation which probably means the model is mis-specified.